# Is there a way to use shell functionality from a Windows service logged in as a user?

Tags: windows-services, windows-shell

We have some C# code that programmatically uses the Windows shell to copy files (actually to unzip them... don't ask) via Shell32.Folder and Shell32.FolderItem (from the Interop.Shell32 assembly, which I think is just a thin wrapper around the shell objects). The code is used in two different contexts, both as services, but in one context it runs as LocalSystem and in the other it runs as a limited user. For now we need it to work in both contexts but eventually we'd like to run it only as a limited user.

The Shell32 functionality works just fine as LocalSystem, even when the "Allow service to interact with desktop" checkbox is unchecked, but doesn't seem to work at all under a specific user account (whether limited or admin). We haven't been able to get any error information -- no dialogs pop up when logged in as the user the service is running as either.

I realize that it may just be a bad idea to use the shell like this from a service, but putting that aside for a moment, do the results I'm seeing sound correct? I haven't found any really definitive documentation that makes me sure that this is a limitation for user accounts but not the Local System account (again, with the desktop interaction thread unchecked). I would have expected that it would fail under both contexts or neither.

Any information on this, or pointers to good info would be helpful. The best I can find is a note [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/171890) saying that services running as user accounts will get "noninteractive" window stations, but it says the same thing about Local System without the SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS flag (which I'm assuming is what the "Allow service to interact with desktop" flag in the service UI does.

Answer (score 0):

If the only reason you're using shell is to unzip, I would recommend using a library like [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) instead.  This is going to be much nicer, for many reasons, but also avoid the problem entirely.

It will work under any account (provided the file access is available), and doesn't require a shell.

Comment: I know, and my goal is to switch to something else, but we have particular requirements related to very large zip files and licensing restrictions that I have to work around first. I'd rather keep the discussion focused on the shell related question rather than alternative libraries.

Comment: Mirosoft's license with PKZip does not cover third-party programs.

Comment: Not sure what you're getting at. Nobody is allowed to write a program that copies files out of a zip folder using shell objects? I don't think there's an issue here.